# Calling Overloaded Operator Function

Tags: c++-cli

I have the overloaded function

```
 Vector3D^ Vector3D:: operator + (Vector3D^ toAdd)  // Adding 2 vectors
{
    Vector3D^ temp = gcnew Vector3D();
    temp->x = x + toAdd->x;
    temp->y = y + toAdd->y;
    temp->z = z + toAdd->z;
    return temp;
}
```

But whenever I call

```
double x1 = Convert::ToDouble(txtAx->Text);
double x2 = Convert::ToDouble(txtBx->Text);
double y1 = Convert::ToDouble(txtBx->Text);
double y2 = Convert::ToDouble(txtBx->Text);
double z1 = Convert::ToDouble(txtBx->Text);
double z2 = Convert::ToDouble(txtBx->Text);

Vector3D vectorA(x1, y1, z1);
Vector3D vectorB(x2, y2, z2);
Vector3D temp;

temp = vectorA + vectorB;
```

I get a  no operator matches these functions errors. Every website suggests doing it this way.

Comment: I'm confused about `^` in the name.

Comment: @erip: This isn't C++. It's C++/CLI. That's why.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Understood.

Comment: Not sure how you expect us to answer this without knowing what either `vectorA` or `vectorB` are. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Theyre two Vectors with doubles x y z

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++/CLI: how to overload an operator to accept reference types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011634/c-cli-how-to-overload-an-operator-to-accept-reference-types)