# Overloading + operator in clr interface class for use in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, clr

I am writing a interface that I would like to implement the + operator.

> IBar.h

```
public interface class IBar : public System::IDisposable
{
    public:
       IBar^ operator+ (IBar^ v);
};
```

> IBarimpl.h

```
private ref class IBarImpl : public IBar
{
public:
    virtual IBar^ operator+ (IBar^ v);
};
```

> IBarimpl.cpp

```
IBar^ IBarImpl::operator+ (IBar^ v)
{
    return gcnew IBarImpl(2.0);
}
```

> factory.h

```
static IBar^ CreateBar(float x);
```

> factory.cpp

```
IBar^ Factory::CreateBar(float x)
{
    return gcnew IBarImpl(x);
}
```

This compiles fine. But when I try to use it:

> test.cs

```
using (IBar bar = Factory.CreateBar(1.0f))
{
    using (IBar bar2 = Factory.CreateBar(1.0f))
    {
        IBar additionResult = bar + bar2;
    }
}
```

It wont compile with the following error:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IBar' and 'IBar'

Any ideas why this is not working?

```
IBar additionResult = bar.op_Addition(bar2);
```

compiles and works fine.

Note that the above code is an EXAMPLE. I am aware that the + function is not actually adding the classes and that the classes have nothing to add. This is purely an example.

Comment: I ended up adding the c++ tag back as it is using c++ from within clr.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011634/c-cli-how-to-overload-an-operator-to-accept-reference-types